# Double Column Validation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data table like this in excel:

```
ColA     ColB
A        1
A        2
B        2
B        3
C        4
```

In a different sheet, I am trying to create two column for which the values will be drop down, using the validation.

For each row of this sheet, the first column will need to be the unique values from ColA, i.e. {A, B, C}, and depending on what was selected there, I want the second column to be presented only with the acceptable choices, i.e. if A is selected, the drop down would show {1, 2}, if B is selected, the drop down would show {2, 3}, ...

Any ideas? I feel I need a function in the validation selection that would return a subset of a list based on a selection criteria, like a SELECTIF ... All the functions I find are aggregate functions that have a nice if version (e.g. COUNTIF, ...)

I prefer to do this without VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a method like [this](http://www.excelcampus.com/tables/dependent-drop-lists/)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jonno: I checked out that method. The only limitation is that the data needs to be sorted to work which won't work in my situation. After researching for so long, it looks like it is the closest I can get without scripting which is good to know. Thanks

Comment: If you search for *Dependent dropdown*, you will find methods that allow you to use Name'd ranges, and don't require sorting.

Comment: If having a sorted list isn't an option, what about building a pivot table that will sort the list for you? It will also filter out all duplicate entries. You could build your dependent drop-down lists based on that. Setting it to display in the classic layout with no grand totals and repeated item labels will give you what you want.